# Having issues getting arcpy.Project_management to execute

Tags: arcpy, error-000208

Python keeps returning me with a Error 000208 on the Project (Project_management()) function. I've checked for improper syntax for all arguments but nothing is striking me as wrong.

```
###Import modules into the script
import sys,arcpy,traceback,os

from arcpy import env
###Set environments
inwrkspc = env.workspace = r"E:\WWU_2017\ENVS423\Assignment_9\Original_Data\Ex9_Data\Ex9_Data_052516\InputProjections.gdb"
outwrkspc = r"E:\WWU_2017\ENVS423\Assignment_9\Original_Data\Ex9_Data\Ex9_Data_052516\OutputProjections.gdb"
print "Workspaces Set"

###For a feature class item in InputProjection.gdb...
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for infc in fcList:
    print infc
    descSRN = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference.name
    print descSRN
    ###if the descSRN(Name) and output proj string is true then pass/ignore this file
    if descSRN == "NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Washington_South_FIPS_4602_Feet":
        print "This data are already projected in the correct coordinate system."
        pass

    ###Otherwise, run reproject 
    else:
        print infc
        outfc = os.path.join(outwrkspc, infc)
        ###Output coordinate system
        outcoordsys = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 HARN StatePlane Washington South FIPS 4602 (US Feet)')
        ###Project tool exported from ArcGIS
        arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc+"_06052017reproj", outcoordsys)
        print "{0} was reprojected to NAD 1983 HARN StatePlane Washington South FIPS 4602 (US Feet)".format(infc)

ArcPy ERRORS:
ERROR 000208: Error creating output feature class
Failed to execute (Project).
```

Comment: There could be many reasons for that error, the most likely is a bad name (outfc+"_06052017reproj" is a bad name if outfc == 'x:\\path\\fc.shp' or if the final name is too long) or name already in use (env.overwriteOutput is undefined in this script) or no write access due to read-only, UAC or disc full. Try printing  outfc+"_06052017reproj" then check to see that it doesn't already exist (or implement overwrite = True) and you've covered most of the likely causes. If you're not projecting because it's already projected shouldn't you be copying to the output?

Comment: I believe your first statement is correct, b/c when I print the outfc+"06052017reproj" it results in the full path being printed which I'm assuming isn't a proper output name for the argument. Additionally, I added in 'env.overwriteOutput = True' to the script. In this exercise I have write permissions, enough disk space, and the output doesn't already exist in the output location.

Comment: A full path should be alright, I'd say most likely the feature class already exists. As your input is fGDB it's unlikely that any of your feature class names contain punctuation (except for underscore), are an SQL reserved word or start with either a number or underscore. There is a limit to the length of a feature class name in a geodatabase of 160 characters http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm but it is unclear whether that limit is inclusive or exclusive of feature dataset name.

Comment: You can use arcpy.Exists http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000021000000 to check if the name exists, and modify the name until the name is not found, but first use arcpy.Exists to ensure your output workspace exists (you may have typed the path wrong). If the name already exists (even as a table, raster, topology, relationship class or feature dataset) and/or the database has a schema lock it can cause this error.

Comment: I got it to work, it happened to be that the output workspace did not exist, like you said. The issue ended up being a spelling mistake on the output workspace pathname. Thanks for your help!